# Camera Causes Crash on Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, computer-vision, webcam

**Context**

I am creating a Barcode Reader / Grader, Image Comparison, and Optical Character Recognition suite for the browser. I've got a USB camera streaming video, currently only changing the Blue value of each pixel and drawing to a canvas.
**(Also using adapter.js)**

**Problem**

After around 2 minutes in Chrome 47, the tab crashes with the "Aww, snap" error message.

**EDIT**

Upon further testing, I've discovered that the problem is not present in the most recent Firefox. The webcam runs consistently, indefinitely, with the same code on Firefox. This would lead me to believe it is an implementation error within Chrome. **(or adapter.js)**

**Code**

```
<video id="vid" autoplay="true"></video>
var video = document.getElementById("vid");

var frame = 0, data = 0;

function loop() {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 640, 480);
    frame = context.getImageData(0, 0, 640, 480);
    data = frame.data;

    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i+=4) {
        data[i+0] -= 0;
        data[i+1] -= 0;
        data[i+2] -= 150;
        data[i+3] -= 0;
    }

    context.putImageData(frame, 0, 0);
}

loop();
```

**Question**

I'm wondering, did I make some obvious error in code? I can't seem to find any memory leaks using the built-in tools with Chrome.

Is this an implementation error on Chrome's part? The problem *feels* like it's trying to close the video stream (improperly), but I can't seem to pinpoint that happening.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Where is `video` defined?

Comment: @towerofnix added the code for declaring video.